# Regex for a line with doubles

Tags: java, regex

I am fairly new to programming and regex is very confusing. I am trying to identify a data line that consists of 3 doubles with spaces in between for example:
500.00 56.48 500.00

I have tried this:

```
data.matches("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$")
```

But this doesn't recognize the line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: step 1: https://regex101.com and actually test your pattern to see how far it gets and double-check that what you think you wrote is what regex101 is telling you your pattern is actually trying to match. Having said that: no need to use `[0-9]` when `\d` exists, and note that those are "the same number, three times" which regex allows you to specify as `(...){3}` so no need to repeat yourself in your pattern.

Comment: Your regexp [works fine on this demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydj2n26r)

Comment: @AlexRudenko that "demo" doesn't test anything. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PGxAm9/1) really should be your only stop necessary to debug anything regular-expression related.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, it's been tested on Java, a green button needs to be pressed to display results of methods `matches`, `find`, `group(0)`.  regex101 shows timeout error.

Comment: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$").matcher(data); if (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group(0)); }`?

Comment: Is the data you're working with only ever plain numbers?

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help. Yes, I only receive a plain number line that I need to check. And it seems I blamed regex too early. The problem wasn't the regex but the white spaces around the incoming line. All I needed to do was trim it.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't do it the way you have tried.

Although the regex pattern you have used works for the numbers you have used, it will fail for a wide range of numbers e.g. `.5` or `5.6E2` which are also `double` numbers.

Given below is the demo with your data and pattern:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "500.00 56.48 500.00";
        System.out.println(data.matches("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

However, it will fail to give you the expected result in the following case:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = ".5 5.6E2 500.00";
        System.out.println(data.matches("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

Even though `.5` and `5.6E2` are valid `double` numbers, your pattern failed to recognize them.

### The recommended way:

You should split the data line on whitespace and try to parse each number using `Double#parseDouble` e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "500.00 56.48 500.00";
        System.out.println(matches(data));

        data = ".5 5.6E2 500.00";
        System.out.println(matches(data));

        data = ".5 500.00";
        System.out.println(matches(data));

        data = ".5 abc 500.00";
        System.out.println(matches(data));
    }

    static boolean matches(String data) {
        String[] nums = data.split("\\s+");
        boolean match = true;

        if (nums.length == 3) {
            for (String num : nums) {
                try {
                    Double.parseDouble(num);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            match = false;
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: Feels like jumping the gun a little? If they have data files that are literally just rows of triplets in a known format, why make the regex more general than it needs to be?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - The OP has mentioned, `I am trying to identify a data line that consists of 3 doubles with spaces in between`. Although [s]he has given an example line of `500.00 56.48 500.00`, going by the statement, the data line can be even `.5 5.6E2 500.00`.

Comment: that's way too far of an assumption: ask them what their data is.

Answer (score -2):

Improve your regex by observing a few things:

- `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`
- you're looking for *the same pattern*, thrice

So, let's do that:

- three times:

  - one or more numbers, optionally followed by
  - a period and then one or more numbers, optionally followed by
  - white space

Which means:

- `(...){3}` where `...` is:

  - `\d+`, optionally followed by
  - `(\.\d+)?` (i.e. zero-or-once), optionally followed by
  - `\s*` (zero-or-more)

Putting that all together, and remembering to use proper string escaping:

```
data.matches("^(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s*){3}$")
```

You can see this working over on https://regex101.com/r/PGxAm9/1, and keeping regex101 bookmarked for future debugging is *highly* recommended.

Comment: This is yet another way of doing the same thing without any improvement. Moreover, it will fail for the `double` numbers, `.5 5.6E2 500.00`. The problem statement is: `I am trying to identify a data line that consists of 3 doubles with spaces in between`

Comment: Nowhere do they say that scientific notation is used, the post _only_ gives an example involving simple decimals, three on a row, with space in between. Their example is pretty clear, so if you want to answer based on details that are _not_ on in the question, verify whether your assumed details are true.